# Change OpenCart Select Option Color from Defaults

Tags: opencart

Using OpenCart, when editing a product, in the option tab, when I add a select menu, I want to have chrome and black as the only two color options. The problem is that it does not allow me to define the colors and gives me a static list of "blue, green, yellow, red".

Where do I edit the select menu's color options for OpenCart?

OpenCart --> Control Panel --> Products --> Edit Product --> Option [tab] --> Create select (auto-completes, just type s for new field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Catalog >> option >> Select [edit]` here you can rename `select` and add extra colors you want etc. by default there are only  "blue, green, yellow, red" so list is showing only these colors.